# How to add custom button to a QMessageBox in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt

I am coding a application which needs a custom buttons in QMessageBox. i managed to create an example in QT designer which is given below.

[image]

i wanted to do this in a QMessageBox.

I am using python 2.6.4 and PyQt4. please, can any one help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is an example of building a custom message box from the ground up.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setText('What to do?')
        msgBox.addButton(QtGui.QPushButton('Accept'), QtGui.QMessageBox.YesRole)
        msgBox.addButton(QtGui.QPushButton('Reject'), QtGui.QMessageBox.NoRole)
        msgBox.addButton(QtGui.QPushButton('Cancel'), QtGui.QMessageBox.RejectRole)
        ret = msgBox.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ... and to get the clicked button, check the value of `ret`.

Answer (score 3):

[manuel-gutierrez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1279003/manuel-gutierrez), why do you inherit from QDilaog? You can inherit from QMessageBox. It's much simpler and less code

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class ErrorWindow(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMessageBox.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        self.addButton(QPushButton("Yes"), QMessageBox.YesRole )
        self.addButton(QPushButton("No"), QMessageBox.NoRole)
        self.addButton(QPushButton("Cancel"), QMessageBox.RejectRole)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ErrorWindow()
    ex.setText("some error")
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard QMessageBox "impose an interpretation of the response", being accepted, rejected or canceled.
Here is a version that allows arbitrary buttons, as much as wanted, and leave the interpreatation up to the user.
And it simplifies the sourcecode a bit.
The argument "buttons" gives a text list, this makes the buttons.
The return value is the text of the clicked botton.
So the user can do what he want's with that.
Note: This might be against UI-Standards and therefore less robust, but hey.
Note2: Since it's 2021, i use PyQt5 and python 3.7
I just posted this in case someone prefer this more generic approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

""" A more generic, a bit simplified message box also known as 'popup' """

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as QW  
    
class Popup(QW.QMessageBox):
    def __init__(
            self, 
            title, 
            text, 
            buttons = ["Ok"]
        ):
        
        super(Popup, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setText(text)
        self.buttons = buttons
        for txt in self.buttons:
            b = QW.QPushButton(txt)
            self.addButton(b, QW.QMessageBox.NoRole)
            
    def do(self):
        answer = self.exec_()
        text = self.buttons[answer]
        return text
    
if __name__ == "__main__": # test
    
    class Tester(QW.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Tester, self).__init__()
    
            btn = QW.QPushButton("do it")
            btn.clicked.connect(self.klick)
            
            layout = QW.QHBoxLayout(self)
            layout.addWidget(btn)
            
        def klick(self, text):
            r = Popup(
                "choose a letter", 
                "What is your favorite\nLetter\namong a to e ?", 
                buttons = "a,b,c,d,e".split(","))

            print("result = ",r.do())
    
    import sys
    app = QW.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Tester()
    widget.setGeometry(400,400,100,100)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```